# Why return echo the whole billing address?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to minimize the billing address if the billing address is already entered before "the customer already bought something or saved his address from his account"

**It works but it doesn't echo address_2 it just echo the whole billing address
,What I'm doing wrong?**

```
//hide billing address from checkout if the address is already entered before
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() && has_billing()){
        unset($fields['billing']);
        $fields['billing'] = array();
    }
    return $fields;
}

// Check the meta of Postcode and Country if they are entered.
function has_billing($user_id = false){
            if(!$user_id)
                $user_id = get_current_user_id();

            $shipping_postcode = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', true );
            $shipping_country = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', true );

            // Fetch more meta for the condition has needed.  
            if($shipping_postcode && $shipping_country){
                return $address_fields['address_2']; 
            }           
}
```

Comment: Your function has_billing has errors and will not work.

Comment: @HowardE Can you explain more? because it work here from my side

Comment: How can it return an array if there is no array defined?

Comment: also, how can `has_billing` be true? It's either returning an array - which would throw an error, since you can't assign a key to an undefined array, or it returns null, since nothing is defined. So your override checkout field should never unset billing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, from your code, is not clear how is defined `$address_fields`
According to https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WooCommerce.html

```
$billing_address_2  = WC()->customer->get_billing_address_2();
```